# androidTestCompile mockito givning Error

Tags: android, testing, android-gradle-plugin, mockito

I'm trying to use Mockito for instrumentation tests, when I add

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'org.objenesis:objenesis' in project ':app'. 
Resolved versions for app (2.1) and test app (2.5) differ. See 
http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

I have no clue what's wrong, I have no org.objenesis dependency specified anywhere in my code (guess it comes through mockito).

Every help, appreciated.

Comment: Mockito shouldn't be in your `app`, only in your `test app`. Can you try `./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration compile` and see if `objenesis` is anywhere in your dependency graph?

Comment: I'll check that, it's actually strange yes, it probably is included in a third-party library I've been using, because I never included it in app myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { force 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1' } }
```

or

Just exclude it in your main project. `exclude group: 'org.objenesis'`

Answer (score 1):

The link in the exception tells you how to remedy this.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1.0'
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can use:

```
androidTestCompile 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the 2nd option however, doesn't seem to work for me.